# How to setup developer environment to develop pulseaudio modules?

Tags: audio, ubuntu-14.04, pulseaudio

I using ubuntu 14.04 and pulseaudio 4.0.
I am compiling very simple test module module-test.c

```
#include <pulsecore/module.h>

int pa__init(pa_module* m){
  return 0;
}
```

when i try to compile it using

```
gcc -g -shared -o module-test.so module-test.c
```

i get this error

```
module-test.c:1:30: fatal error: pulsecore/module.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pulsecore/module.h>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
```

i looked in `/usr/include` and there is no folder name `pulsecore`. i tried installing development packages like `libpulse-dev` but that didn't solve this issue.

Comment: this might help ...   sudo apt-get build-dep pulseaudio  ... although on Ubuntu 17.10 it does not include that missing header ... this is one of the reasons why its best to keep your OS kit current  ... 14.04 is a tad long on the tooth

Comment: getting this error E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list

Comment: that new error is easily google-able ... do not allow youself to be dependent on anyone if you wish to become a productive software developer ... keep in mind many of us taught ourselves programming out of a book by ourselves before the internet existed

Comment: I resolved E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list and successfully executed this sudo apt-get build-dep pulseaudio command but my original error remains.

Comment: @ScottStensland, it's sad you try to send people to google when google actually send people here. You should have written an answer when it was foundable...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is locate the directory named `pulsecore`. You found it in `/usr/include` but to help other people, you can locate the file `pulsecore/module.h` with the command:

```
find / -name module.h
```

To me, it returns:

```
alpereira7@omen:~$ find / -name module.h
/home/alpereira/pulseaudio/src/pulsecore/module.h
```

So to me, `pulsecore` is in `/home/alpereira/pulseaudio/src`.

I will compile using:

```
gcc -g -shared -I/home/alpereira7/pulseaudio/src -o module-test.so module-test.c
```

Now I still have errors:

```
#error "Please include config.h before including this file!"
```

Which is rather explicit! So I added it to my script:

```
#include <config.h> 
#include <pulsecore/module.h>

int pa__init(pa_module* m)
{
  return 0;
}
```

I need to indicate the location of `config.h` so the final compilation command is:

```
gcc -g -shared -I/home/alpereira7/pulseaudio -I/home/alpereira7/pulseaudio/src -o module-test.so module-test.c
```